# How to update php version 5.3.8 into php version 5.6

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, xampp, version

I use Facebook integration using CodeIgniter and I use PHP version 5.3.8 
and when I click on Facebook login page it will show the error.

> "Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'The
>   Facebook SDK v4 requires PHP version 5.4 or higher.' in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\coaherr_test\autoload.php:32 Stack trace: #0
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\coaherr_test\fbconfig.php(4): require_once() #1 {main}
>   thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\coaherr_test\autoload.php on line 32"

How to resolve this issue.

Comment: you need to consult with hosting service provider once

Comment: Uninstall XAMPP, reinstall a new version

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade your xampp

> 1. Download latest portable version of XAMPP .
> 2. Extract the archive(not where XAMPP already installed).
> 3. Copy the PHP folder from the extracted archive.
> 4. Keep back up of htdocs folder which is in installed XAMPP directory. ...
> 5. Paste the htdocs folder which you copied from the extracted archive.

Answer (score 0):

1. backup Your all htdocs files and Mysql databases(keep backup outside XAMPP folder. ex: place it on another drive).
2. Uninstall XAMPP completely
3. and [Download Setup here](https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html)
4. Install it and place your files and databases.